# PDO duplicate row

Tags: php, pdo

I'm looking for a way to duplicate this row using PDO. I don't want to retype all the values.

```
$strsql="INSERT INTO `dreamyAuctions`(`category`,`type`,`city`,`host`,`host_name`,`title`,`fee`,`base_fee`,`min_fee`,`max_fee`,`min_fee2`,`max_fee2`,`last_fee_change`,`seats`,`retail_price`,`asking_price`,`details`,`delivery`,`delivery_time`,`timer`,`start_date`,`free_bids`,`seats_taken`,`show_on_homepage`,`vet_players`,`tournament`,`final_round`,`refresh`,`repost`,`started`,`completed`,`active`,`create_date`,`complete_date`,`minimum_auctions`,`video`,`video2`,`show_pinterest`,`bid_fee`,`saves`,`seat_free`) 
VALUES(\"$cat\",\"$contest_type\",\"$city\",\"$host\",\"$host_name\",'" . mysql_real_escape_string($title) . "',\"$base_fee\",\"$base_fee\",\"$min_fee\",\"$max_fee\",\"$min_fee2\",\"$max_fee2\",now(),\"$seats\",\"$retail\",\"$ask_price\",'" . mysql_real_escape_string($details) . "',\"$delivery\",\"$dtime\",'11',\"$start_date\",\"$free_bids\",'0',\"$show\",\"$vet\",\"$tournament\",'N',\"$refresh\",'Y','N','N','Y',now(),'',\"$min_auctions\",'" . mysql_real_escape_string($video) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($video2) . "',\"$pinterest\",\"$bfee\",\"$pre_set_saves\",\"$free_to_seat\")";
mysql_query($strsql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());
$chkrow1=mysql_affected_rows($connect);
$aid=mysql_insert_id();
```

I tried

```
$auctionId=1;
//create new table with old data
$st = $db->prepare("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tbl SELECT * FROM `dreamyAuctions` WHERE `id`=:auctionId;
INSERT INTO dreamyAuctions SELECT * FROM temp_tbl;
DROP TABLE temp_tbl;"); // need to filter for next auction
$st->bindParam(':auctionId', $auctionId); // filter
$st->execute();
```

This is not working

Comment: What doesn't work? What error did you get? And why are you mixing `mysql_*` functions with PDO?

Comment: I'm changing from mysql to PDO. No error's just a blank page with nothing inserted in the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to insert into dreamyAuctions with a straight select from the same table for the given auction_id - you just have to list all the fields with the exception of auction_id as this is the primary key (assumption) and cannot be duplicated.

```
INSERT INTO `dreamyAuctions`(`category`,`type`,`city`,`host`,`host_name`,`title`,`fee`,`base_fee`,`min_fee`,`max_fee`,`min_fee2`,`max_fee2`,`last_fee_change`,`seats`,`retail_price`,`asking_price`,`details`,`delivery`,`delivery_time`,`timer`,`start_date`,`free_bids`,`seats_taken`,`show_on_homepage`,`vet_players`,`tournament`,`final_round`,`refresh`,`repost`,`started`,`completed`,`active`,`create_date`,`complete_date`,`minimum_auctions`,`video`,`video2`,`show_pinterest`,`bid_fee`,`saves`,`seat_free`) 
SELECT
`category`,`type`,`city`,`host`,`host_name`,`title`,`fee`,`base_fee`,`min_fee`,`max_fee`,`min_fee2`,`max_fee2`,`last_fee_change`,`seats`,`retail_price`,`asking_price`,`details`,`delivery`,`delivery_time`,`timer`,`start_date`,`free_bids`,`seats_taken`,`show_on_homepage`,`vet_players`,`tournament`,`final_round`,`refresh`,`repost`,`started`,`completed`,`active`,`create_date`,`complete_date`,`minimum_auctions`,`video`,`video2`,`show_pinterest`,`bid_fee`,`saves`,`seat_free`
FROM `dreamyAuctions` WHERE auction_id=:auctionId
```

The reason your temporary table insert is not working is because the primary key is going with the data and you cannot duplicate it when inserting back into the main table.

Answer (score 1):

to see the errors of PDO see this example with your code:

```
// Connect to MySQL via PDO
try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=users_db", "root", "");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// try to execute the query, if there is a error it goes to the catch block.
try {
$st = $db->prepare("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tbl SELECT * FROM `dreamyAuctions` WHERE `id`=:auctionId;
INSERT INTO dreamyAuctions SELECT * FROM temp_tbl;
DROP TABLE temp_tbl;"); // need to filter for next auction
$st->bindParam(':auctionId', $auctionId); // filter
$st->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the above but I'm still not getting any error messages and no insert

Comment: @user2320607 add this at the top of your file `ini_set('display_errors', true);` You should now see a error.